# how to attach instance to load balances automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are using Amazon Web Services EC2 to create webapp servers which are then attached to an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB). The instances eventually use the url of the load balancer itself to request .

Case:

I am running a web application, which is distributed over multiple AWS EC2 instances behind a AMAZON Elastic Load Balancer but when i load web app to my Bitnami server it is running , i use my load balancer URL to run it , but later instances are not updated automatically to my load balances n my URL not working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an Auto Scaling Group and a Launch Configuration. Then, you can attach the load balancer to the group and as the group scales up and down the instances will automatically be added to the load balancer.

If you don't want/can't use a scaling group, then you will need a separate process which monitors your server and adds them to the load balancer as needed.

Comment: hi i have done every bit of things as what you have explained but instance are not attaching automatically to my auto scale group

Comment: The instances don't attach to the auto scale group. When you scale the ASG, the instances will automatically attach to the ELB. There isn't a way to 'automatically' add instances to an ASG.

Comment: okee but some one told me , we have to follow a script to do that , and can u help me in user data ... i am not able to understand it how to attach my .war file with bitnami tomcat instance .

Comment: I think you need to ask a new question for this.